# windows phone more than one navigation keys

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, windows-phone-7, navigation

i am trying to navigate on windows phone 7.1 from one page to another , using more than one navigation keys

```
Me.NavigationService.Navigate(New Uri(String.Format("/ImagePage.xaml?tag={0}", li.Tag), UriKind.Relative))
```

this one works perfect...

but  when i am adding and a second key :

```
Me.NavigationService.Navigate(New Uri(String.Format("/ImagePage.xaml?tag={0}?tag2={1}", li.Tag,l2.tag), UriKind.Relative))
```

but the result on second page is :

tag = "tag"?tag2="tag2"

where "tag" = contet of tag
and "tag2" = contet of tag2

any ideas ... the wrong must be on the ? operator , but i am not sure :S
i have try many others , none of theme seems correct :O

thank you any way !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There should be AND symbol the second time and not a question mark two times.

```
/ImagePage.xaml?tag={0}&tag2={1}"
```

Answer (score 3):

The second `?` should be a `&`:

```
Me.NavigationService.Navigate(New Uri(String.Format("/ImagePage.xaml?tag={0}&tag2={1}", ...
```